# Limit as x approaches infinity with radical numerator

Tags: calculus, limits

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{1+4x^6}}{2-x^3}$

The answer should be -2 but I just can't work out how to do it.

Comment: Hint: For very large $x$, $\sqrt{4x^6+1} \approx \sqrt{4x^6} = 2x^3$.

Comment: Ohhhh this helped perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: 
\begin{align}
\frac{\sqrt{1+4x^6}}{2-x^3}=\frac{\sqrt{1/x^6+4}}{2/x^3-1}
\end{align}